# VS 2017 Update 3 - .Net Core 2 SPA - Angular | How to expand the template and add custom CSS and JS

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, single-page-application, webpack-2

I'm kinda new to WebPack and Angular 4. I've seen many articals that intro the new template but none of them walk-though on how to use it in real-world apps, I saw some posts that define the custom CSS for each angular component and import or require it to use it. I think my case is different (maybe i am wrong).

First step to utilize the template is to create my layout HTML which is based on limitless template, limitless is using a lot of 3rd party JS libraries such as Ace, Beautify, BlockUI, Pace, etc and at least couple of CSS files, and custom JS files to get the template to work. I understand that I should break the UI into components such as header, nav-bar etc.. but I will worry about that later.

I have a lot of question, and it all related on what\how\where (basics)!

Package.json

1: What is the difference between dependence and devDependence?

2: If I will use moment, underscore, ace or any vendor JS library, should I add it to dependence or devDependence?

Webpack.config

3: I think next step is to add those packages to webpack.config.vendor.js but add to treeShakableModules or nonTreeShakableModules and what is the difference?

4: How to use those packages in my app? I tried to consume moment() from browser console and I learned that these libraries to be exported to global and the way WebPack is doing it is by defining plugin new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: "jquery", jQuery: "jquery" }) I tried to do the same for moment or underscore but still not working.

5- Where should I put my custom CSS and JS for the limitless template to work, inside ClientApp\assets? When I add them there and after running webpack I searched the bundled files and couldn't find my custom JS and CSS.

6- Basically the custom CSS and JS will be used by the _Layout.chtml and they should be global for all other components to use them, so how I can consume it in _layout and in other angular components?

I'm sorry, I've asked a lot of question, maybe you can answer some or all, or direct me to a tutorial, post online that expand the VS template, and add more functionality, explain each aspect of the template instead of limited introduction about the template.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Angular CLI, MS SPA template is not straight forward and require a lot of work to get things to work

Answer (score 0):

1.In packages.json dependancies are used for publishing the final application, while devdependancis are extra when developing.

2.dependence

3.treeShakableModules are modules that have alot of code removed from then when publishing

4.no idea
5. i am also searching for an answer, u can also use wwwroot to put custom css and add it in the header as a link

6. go to 5